# Idiomatic translation of “Art will save me” to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Is there a more idiomatic translation Into Latin of the sentence “Art will save me.” than “Ars servabit me fac.”?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Where did you find that translation?

Comment: @chuff: What has imperative "fac" got to do with it? Delete and begin to approach the target.

Comment: I have no Latin at all.  I started with the Google translate result and then looked at other sites. The reverse translate results came close with the above translation.

Comment: @chuff: Net translation sites are next to useless (for Latin); "ars me servabit" should do it.

Comment: Not surprised by observation on net sites, tony. Thanks for assist.

Comment: At least in classical Latin ars means "skill, dexterity" or the like. What sort of art is it that will save you?

Answer (score 4):

> Ars servabit me fac

This means, literally, "art will save me—make!".

I would remove the "make!" (*fac*), but the rest is pretty good. If you want it a bit more idiomatic:

- The most natural Latin word order would be *ars mē servābit* (though no order is *wrong*, per se)
- If you want it to sound more like a motto, you can reduce it to *ars servat*: "art saves [people]"

There's not an exact equivalent for English "art" in Latin, but *ars* works for many circumstances.